# How to populate 2 text boxes and 1 dropdown from onchange of a first dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show the coordinates of a galaxy in text boxes and populate a dropdown based on the result of a first dropdown. I have the linked dropdowns working, but cannot work out how to populate the relevant text boxes

The answers I've found answer one problem or the other, but not both, and combining the answers I find isn't working either

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div class="form-group"><div class="row"><div class="col"><label for="target-list">Target Name:</label></div></div> <select id="choices" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Target Name" class="button form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></select>
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div> <div class="form-group"><label>Right Ascension:</label> <input id="Right Ascension" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div> <div class="form-group"><label>Declination:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div>

 <div><label class="wrapper" for="states">Filter</label>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //init data
  var arrayList = [{
      "Id": 0,
      "Name": "Select a target...",
      "Right Ascension": "HH:MM:SS.S",
      "Declination":"DD:MM:SS.S"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "M15",
        "Right Ascension": "21:29:58.3",
      "Declination":"+12:10:01.2"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "M27"

    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "NGC891"
    }

  ];


  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++) {
    $('#choices').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
  }


});

$("#choices").change(function() {
  // $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
  //use this if using external json sets

  var $selection = $("#choices option:selected");
  var key = $selection.val();

  var vals = [];

  $(".imghere").attr("src", "");

  switch (key) {
    case '1':
      text: ["Please Select a Filter","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red", "Green", "Blue"]; 
      break;
    case '2':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"] //data.Berkeley 73.split(",");
      break;
    case '3':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"] //data.Czernic 27.split(",");
      break;
    case '0':
      vals = ['Please Select a Filter...'];
  }


  var $secondChoice = $("#filter");
  $secondChoice.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });

});


$("#filter").change(function() {
  var $filter = $("#filter option:selected").val();
  var baseurl = "https://github.com/brychanjames/RTI-Simulator/blob/master/";
  var $showimg = baseurl + $filter + ".jpg";
  //$(".imghere").attr("src",$showimg); use this, the next line is demo purposes
  $(".imghere").attr("src", $showimg); /*use variable in place of the placeholder image*/


});
```

I want to be able to display the Right Ascension and Declination of a target and have the dropdown populate with the values shown, I've created a fiddle that shows the select boxes working with the text boxes inert here

[http://jsfiddle.net/brychang/jtf8k5ym/33/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it, but without printing the name from the arrays, which means you'd have to populate the values by yourself by changing 'test' and 'test2' in the jquery code.

Change:

```
<input id="Right Ascension" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

to

```
<input id="right" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
<input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

JQUERY:
Edit the values "test" and "test2" to whatever

```
  switch (key) {
    case '1':
      text: ["Please Select a Filter","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red", "Green", "Blue"]; 
      $('#right').val('test');
      $('#desc').val('test2');
      break;
    case '2':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"] //data.Berkeley 73.split(",");
      $('#right').val('test');
      $('#desc').val('test2');
      break;
    case '3':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"] //data.Czernic 27.split(",");
      $('#right').val('test');
      $('#desc').val('test2');
      break;
    case '0':
      vals = ['Please Select a Filter...'];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed, you have been hugely helpful! thank you so much for this